# Why is this image not overwriting the image in child template?

Tags: python, html, django, templates

I have in my base.html ("in my templates folder same level as manage.py"):

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="/"
        >{% block brand %}<img src="{% static 'logo.png' %} " />{% endblock%}</a
      >
```

However the block is still showing the same image of the child template, how can I overwrite it? just the "/" page only shows static/logo.png? and the child template shows reviews/logo.png.

I have a static folder in the main project folder and a template folder, I have added their  respective config in settings.py see:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],

STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / 'static']
```

here is the child template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %} {%load static%} {% block brand %}<img
  src="{% static 'reviews/logo.png' %}"
/>{%endblock%}
```

Comment: How does the child template look like?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem do you suggest any debbuging tips?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem findstatic shows :
Found 'logo.png' here:
  C:\Users\PERSONAL\Desktop\Portafolio\bookr\static\logo.png

Comment: using findstatic in reviews/logo.png reviews/logo.png showsFound 'reviews/logo.png' here:
  C:\Users\PERSONAL\Desktop\Portafolio\bookr\reviews\static\reviews\logo.png